# Redirect ignore last URL segment

Tags: redirect, urls, htaccess

I have a page on my Wordpress website that I want to effectively have a wildcard on the end of the URL.

The URL is "https://www.mywebsite.com/map". I want that same page to be directed too if it is anything like:

- "https://www.mywebsite.com/map/7690e382-786a-412d-9711-966a708c0a38"
- "https://www.mywebsite.com/map/ef5ae8ba-fcbd-4184-b501-bd79ecdd4ee2"

I need the URL to keep the segment though, as I have some JS on the /map page that will read it and send the value to an IFrame.

Is this possible via Wordpress admin or via the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by adding the following two lines to my .htaccess, right before the rest of the other WordPress rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/map/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /map [L,P]
```

Bottom of my .htaccess with the rules looked like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/map/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /map [L,P]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Your rule can be simplified to a single directive, eg. `RewriteRule ^map/. /map [NC,P]`. However, _proxying_ the request in this way is very inefficient. There should be a more efficient "WordPress" (non Apache/`.htaccess`) way of doing this. (NB: You should avoid editing the code in the WordPress code block - if that is what you have done here - since WordPress itself manages this section. Your rule just needs to be near the top of the file, _before_ the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker. It can go _before_ the `RewriteEngine On` directive - you do not need to repeat this directive.)